# Inject one bean's name into constructor of another bean

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations

```
public class1 {
  @Bean(name = "s1")
  public Class1 s1 {}

  @Bean(name = "s2")
  public Class2 s2 {}

  @Bean(name = "s3")
  public Class3 s3 (@Name("s1"), @Name("s2")) {}

  @Bean(name = "s4")
  public Class4 s4 {
     return new somefunction(@Name("s3"))
  }
}
```

Suppose we have sth like above. Where clearly Bean s3 depends on s1 and s2. And now I'd like to pass output of s3 into somefunction of another Bean s4, what should I do?

It seems @Name("s3") not work here, and maybe I should use other annotations? thx

Comment: yes, I think so, an instance of s3 that can be passed into newfunction in s4